# Is there a way to find what build command visual studio code is using internally?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, compilation

I am compiling a program with visual studio and I need to figure out an equivalent cmd command so I can use Emscripten. I have tried to figure it out by pointing to the same libraries but it is not working. Is there a way to find what build command visual studio is using internally?

Output messages:

```
cl /c /IC:\Users\Drago\source\repos\OpenGL\Dependencies\GLFW\include /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl /O2 /Oi /Oy- /GL /D WIN32 /D NDEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /Gy /fp:precise /permissive- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Release\\" /Fd"Release\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /FC /errorReport:prompt src\Application.cpp

"/OUT:C:\Users\Drago\source\repos\OpenGL\Release\OpenGL.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Drago\source\repos\OpenGL\Dependencies\GLFW\lib-vc2017" glfw3.lib opengl32.lib User32.lib Gdi32.lib Shell32.lib /MANIFEST "/MANIFESTUAC:level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG "/PDB:C:\Users\Drago\source\repos\OpenGL\Release\OpenGL.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG:incremental "/LTCGOUT:Release\OpenGL.iobj" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT "/IMPLIB:C:\Users\Drago\source\repos\OpenGL\Release\OpenGL.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH Release\Application.obj
```

Comment: Visual studio or visual studio code?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019

Comment: MSBuild is a Make alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In project properties for C/C++ / General.  Locate "Suppress Startup Banner" and force it to **No**.  (Equivalent to not specifying `/nologo` as a command line param)

When the project builds, you'll see the command line arguments passed to cl.exe in the output window.

You can achive the same effect with the linker showing the command line params.  Just look for "Suppress Startup Banner" under Linker/General and set it to **No** as well to see the command line params passed to link.exe

[image]

Comment: What would be an equivalent Clang compilation command to my output messages?

Comment: you want to port a cl.exe command line args to clang?  Or you want to use clang with Visual Studio and observe the command line args passed to it?

Comment: Well ultimately, I need to use emcc (emscripten) but emcc has the same basic options as clang I believe.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't immediately recognize what emscripten was until I looked it up.  Porting C++ code to a different platform is never easy. Start by enumerating the defines (`/D` options) getting passed to the code and ascertain if they are relevant and need to be passed to your other compiler. Otherwise, just going file by file to get it to compile and adding tests might be the only sure fire way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Project >> Properties.

Some of the main panels like 'C/C++' and 'Linker' have a sub panel called 'Command Line' There you can find many settings.